# Creating tkinter labels with links using a for loop results in all links pointing to the same URL. Why?

Tags: python, tkinter-label

I need to create a lot of labels with links (binds) in tkinter.
I am using a for loop to go through a dataset to create the labels.
But in the result all labes link to the same URL (the last).

This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import os

root = Tk()

dataset =[['Google', 'http://www.google.com'], ['Ecosia', 'http://www.ecosia.org'], ['IBM', 'http://www.ibm.com']]

def create_links(dataset):
    docs = []
    for i, data in enumerate(dataset):
        docs.append(Label(root, text=data[0], fg="blue", cursor="hand2"))
        docs[i].bind('<Button-1>', lambda e: os.system(f'start {data[1]}'))
        docs[i].pack()


create_links(dataset)
root.mainloop()
```

If running the for loop directly (not in function) ist works fine.
Why is that?

In my real application I need to run the for loop in a function.
Help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why aren't you using list of tuples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was noted in the comments, your issue arises from the fact that (as is noted [here](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-do-lambdas-defined-in-a-loop-with-different-values-all-return-the-same-result)), your `data` variable is not local to the lambdas, but is defined in the outer scope, and is evaluated when the lambda is called ***not when it is defined***!

The workaround is to define a local variable in your lambdas, which is evaluated when the lambda is defined.

In code:

```py
def create_links(dataset):
    docs = []
    for i, data in enumerate(dataset):
        docs.append(Label(root, text=data[0], fg="blue", cursor="hand2"))
        docs[i].bind('<Button-1>', lambda e, l=data[1]: os.system(f'start {l}'))
        docs[i].pack()
```